# Unity UI Slider to change UI Text

Tags: c, user-interface, unity-game-engine, uitextfield, uislider

Ok Im using unity 4.6 and have a UI slider visible to the player. Beside the slider I have a UI Text which is showing a String of 500. The Slider head is at the right hand side (500) and can be slid left towards what I want to be 0.
I have the following code in place but when i slide the slider the Text value starts at 500 and automatically changes to 0.99 and moves the whole way down to 0 on the left hand side. If i was to slide it back up to the right hand side it has a value of 1.

```
public class SliderUITextUpdate : MonoBehaviour {

string sliderTextString = "500";
public Text sliderText;

public void textUpdate(float textUpdateNumber)
{
    sliderTextString = textUpdateNumber.ToString ();
    sliderText.text = sliderTextString;
} 
}
```

This script is attached to a Manager object (just an empty gameobject) and then the text game object is applied in the inspector.
On the slider object I am using the OnValueChanged() ability in the inspector. To which I have attached the Manager gameobject and set it to use SliderUITexture.textUpdate

Any help would be great thanks !

Comment: Have you changed minValues and maxValues on the slider ?

Comment: In the inspector the direction is Left to Right, Min Value 0, Max Value 1...the Value underneath that is set to 1

Comment: So thats it. minValue and maxValue decide the result of the slider. If you need a value between 0 to 500, you need to set minValue to 0 and maxValue to 500, either in inspector or (ugly) on code like the first answer.

Comment: Thanks alot !! 

seperate query, would save me writing another question...if I was to take the number that the slider stopped on and when they hit an OK button, how would add that number to a seperate number in another script. I have a Score script with a score variable and i know to call that you use Score.score  ??

Comment: You need either a reference to another script and call some public variable / method with the value, or to send a unity message to  another script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class SliderUITextUpdate : MonoBehaviour {

string sliderTextString = "500";
public Text sliderText;
public Slider mainSlider;

void Awake(){
   mainSlider.maxValue = 500;
}

public void textUpdate(float textUpdateNumber)
{
    sliderTextString = textUpdateNumber.ToString ();
    sliderText.text = sliderTextString;
} 
}
```

get the referece for that slider in inspector